# How to handle multiple inputs for the same variable in react?

Tags: reactjs

My colleague has been working on a small project and needs my help with it, I have barely any experience in react and have been trying to use my knowledge from other languages to handle this problem, however I have come to my limits after searching the web for hours and not finding an efficient way to handle this issue without having to rewrite most of the code.

So the problem is the following: We have customer orders with different variables, (i.e. Loading Country)
These are displayed in a table like this (we map over the data and print this tr/td for every order):

```
<td><input type="text" onChange={(e) => setLoadingCountry(e.target.value)} className={"lcountry"+data.rowid} value={data.array_options.options_lcountry}></input></td>
<td><input type="text" onChange={(e) => setLoadingZip(e.target.value)} className={"lpostcode"+data.rowid} value={data.array_options.options_lpostcode}></input></td>
```

`setLoadingCountry` is used for a useState.

With an update button for each row at the end:

`<td><button className={data.id} onClick={(e) => handleCoData(e.target.className)}>Update</button></td>`

`handleCoData` is a function I made, since we get the initial data from a json and I put the json into a useState array, this function handles that array after button click like the following:

```
const handleCoData = (coID) => {
        setCoData(
            coData.map((co) => 
                co.id == coID
                    ? {...co, array_options: {
                        options_lcountry: loadingCountry,
                        options_lpostcode: loadingZip
                    }}
                    : {...co}

            )
        );
        console.log(coID);
        console.log(coData);
    };
```

Now: One Problem, which is the smaller one, is that we can only update one row at a time, since changing 2 countries from 2 rows without updating inbetween will overwrite the value of the first loading country in the useState.
The bigger problem is that, when you only want to change the loading country, and then click update, the Zip is either empty, because it was never set by the use state, or it has the value from another row which was changed previously. Is there any way to get the value from that specific row for that specific field?

If this question needs changes or additional information please tell me so, as I said I do not have much experience in React, and it is not my project either so I have no idea what might be needed to fully understand the issue.

Thank you.

Edit:
I was not able to make a codepen, since it would show a syntax error that I can't figure out quickly ( there isn't one in the actual code), but here is the code which includes all the things needed.

```
//import Data from "../../data.json";

const CombinedComponents = (apiKey) => {
  const [loadingCountry, setLoadingCountry] = useState([]);
  const [loadingZip, setLoadingZip] = useState([]);

  const [coData, setCoData] = useState(Data);
  console.log(coData);

  const handleCoData = (coID) => {
    setCoData(
      coData.map((co) =>
        co.id == coID
          ? {
              ...co,
              array_options: {
                options_lcountry: loadingCountry,
                options_lpostcode: loadingZip
              }
            }
          : { ...co }
      )
    );
    console.log(coID);
    console.log(coData);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        {visible && <TableHeadView1 />}
        <tbody>
          {coData.map((data) => (
            <tr>
              <td>{data.ref}</td>
              <td>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  onChange={(e) => setLoadingCountry(e.target.value)}
                  className={"lcountry" + data.rowid}
                  value={data.array_options.options_lcountry}
                ></input>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  onChange={(e) => setLoadingZip(e.target.value)}
                  className={"lpostcode" + data.rowid}
                  value={data.array_options.options_lpostcode}
                ></input>
              </td>
              <td>
                <button
                  className={data.id}
                  onClick={(e) => handleCoData(e.target.className)}
                >
                  Update
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is what the array `coData` looks like (ofcourse with many more entries):

```
[{
  "id": "11480",
  "array_options": {
    "options_lcountry": "1",
    "options_lpostcode": "80190",

  }
}]
```

Comment: It would help if you posted a codepen or snippet with your problem

Comment: @msmoore Will do it right now

Comment: Imho you should avoid mixing className and IDs. Classes should be only about the styling. Also, I think your onClick should use `data.id` directly. Concerning the use of map, some code is missing. Something might be wrong with the `key` attribute you give to your `<tr>` element. Could you dump the array structure for us also?

Comment: @msmoore I added a code snippet at the bottom of the question, it should show everything needed.

Comment: Thank you, it is way better with this

Comment: @ThomasZimmermann Also added an example of the json that is retrieved and then made into an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here your problem resides in using a single state value for handling multiple input values. If I was to do it, I'd only use the main array all the time, giving me multiple fields to change from. Currently, your update button only handles the React state, which is purely front end. You could use it to send the update to your backend instead.

My take on this one would be using these functions for inputs 'onChange' props:

```
  const handleCountryUpdate = (id, value) => {
    coData.find(it => it.id === id).array_options.options_lcountry = value;
    setCoData([...coData]); // Using an array copy to override the state
  };

  const handlePostCodeUpdate = (id, value) => {
    coData.find(it => it.id === id).array_options.options_lpostcode = value;
    setCoData([...coData]);
  };

...

<input type="text"
       onChange={(e) => handlePostCodeUpdate(data.id, e.target.value)}
       className={"lpostcode" + data.rowid}
       value={data.array_options.options_lpostcode}>
</input>
```

Another way around would be to use a child component state to do the job

```
...
{coData.map((data) => <TableRow key={data.id}
                                data={data}
                                handleCoData={handleCoData}/>)}
...

const TableRow = props => {
  const {data, handleCoData} = props;
  const [loadingCountry, setLoadingCountry] = useState(data.array_options.options_lcountry);
  const [loadingZip, setLoadingZip] = useState(data.array_options.options_lpostcode);

  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{data.ref}</td>
      <td>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={(e) => setLoadingCountry(e.target.value)}
          className={"lcountry" + data.rowid}
          value={data.array_options.options_lcountry}
        ></input>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={(e) => setLoadingZip(e.target.value)}
          className={"lpostcode" + data.rowid}
          value={data.array_options.options_lpostcode}
        ></input>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button
          className={data.id}
          onClick={(e) => handleCoData(e.target.className)}
        >
          Update
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
}
```

Comment: We actually had the same solution, but the problem is that when you only send the country to the backend (node, made by us) it makes another API call to a seperate database which actually has the orders (this API was not made by us), and it seems to have a bug, that when you i.e. only send the country it empties all  the other fields. Thats why we took the approach to update the whole row at once, so we dont lose the old values.

Comment: Maybe the second example suits your case better then

Comment: I will try it right now, thank you very much, seems like a viable solution to me.

Comment: You are very welcome, have fun with React !